# How to write this query without cursor in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this table `ScoreDetails`, 2 columns (there are more, but only 2 needed or this query). One is `ScoreDate`, `Score`.

The structure is like

```
2012:03:27: 5:06:37:134           27
2012:03:27: 5:06:37:276           37
2012:03:28: 4:12:97:019           19
2012:03:29: 7:06:37:134           7
2012:03:29: 8:06:37:134           0
2012:04:03: 12:06:37:739          16
2012:04:04: 23:21:15:834          33
2012:04:04: 15:08:24:697          12
2012:04:06: 5:06:37:134           0
2012:04:09: 5:06:37:134           2
2012:04:13: 5:06:37:134           92
```

What I want is to write a select query, **without** using temp table or cursor. Such that, I have a column that starts from 1 and keeps on increasing as 2,3 and so on, upto when the score is non-zero. But as soon as a zero is encountered in score column, it resets to 1 and then start again. Like this...

```
2012:03:27: 5:06:37:134           27       1
2012:03:27: 5:06:37:276           37       2
2012:03:28: 4:12:97:019           19       3
2012:03:29: 7:06:37:134           7        4
2012:03:29: 8:06:37:134           0        0
2012:04:03: 12:06:37:739          16       1
2012:04:04: 23:21:15:834          33       2
2012:04:04: 15:08:24:697          12       3
2012:04:06: 5:06:37:134           0        0
2012:04:09: 5:06:37:134           2        1
2012:04:13: 5:06:37:134           92       2
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You might want to have a look at CTEs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common table expressions for that. I defined 2 anchor queries: one for records with 0 score and the other for the first record. Then you build up the result based on previous results until you find 0 score.

```
with cte
as
(
  select ScoreDate, Score, ScoreRank, 0 as Value
  from (select ScoreDate, Score, dense_rank() over (order by ScoreDate) ScoreRank
        from ScoreDetails) X
  where Score = 0

  union all

  select ScoreDate, Score, ScoreRank, 1 as Value
  from (select ScoreDate, Score, dense_rank() over (order by ScoreDate) ScoreRank
        from ScoreDetails) X
  where Score <> 0 and ScoreRank = 1

  union all

  select X.ScoreDate, X.Score, X.ScoreRank, cte.Value + 1 as Value
  from (select ScoreDate, Score, dense_rank() over (order by ScoreDate) ScoreRank
        from ScoreDetails) X
  inner join cte
  on X.ScoreRank = cte.ScoreRank + 1
  and X.Score <> 0
)

select ScoreDate, Score, Value, ScoreRank
from cte
order by ScoreDate
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34b0c/9)

Comment: Thanks, that did the work. But can you please explain what happened in the 3rd select part? I mean the last query inside the cte, that has inner join to cte itself? It went straight over my head. How can you join a cte to a query that is inside the cte itself?

Comment: That's how CTE works in a recursive way. There's a link in the comments under your question to a MSDN page explaining CTE. Do a bit of reading and it will become more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I won't spoil the fun of finding the solution yourself, but I will give you some hints on how to split the problem into smaller pieces:

- Find all the records where the score is reset. Let's call this subquery the `resetRecords`.
- Join the records of the original table to the `resetRecords`, such that every record has "its" reset record (i.e., the reset record that provides the base for its count).
- Use [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to assign the numbers.

Try to do this one step at a time. Beware: It won't be a simple query, so a solution with temp tables or cursors *might* be easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with x as (
select *, sum(case when Score=0 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by ScoreDate) as grp
from ScoreDetails
)
select ScoreDate, Score, row_number() over (partition by grp order by ScoreDate)
from x
order by ScoreDate
```

(*as soon as a zero is encountered in score column, it resets to 1 and then start again*, you said)